# Determing of an input is real in Matlab

Tags: matlab, validation

This is a simple question but I'm just now learning MATLAB. I am attempting to write a function that determines whether the user input is real. I am using `isnumeric` and `isscalar` and I was going to use `imag(x) ==0` to make sure it didn't have an imaginary part but I'm getting an error with negative numbers. Any suggestions would be great!

```
function y = isR(x)
  if isnumeric(x) && isscalar(x) && imag(x)==0
    disp('true')
  else
    disp('false')
  end
end
```

Error MATLAB:unassignedOutputs

Comment: Can you paste a code sample of what you did/tried and also the error message you got?

Comment: You're displaying your decision, not returning it.  But you also promise a return value...

Comment: Thanks everyone! That makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

You write that you are getting:

`Error MATLAB:unassignedOutputs`

So MatLab is complaining about an output being unassigned. Hmm, let's have a look at your function declaration:

`function y = isR(x)`

In this, `isR` is the function name, `x` is a function input argument, and `y` is a function output argument. Matlab is complaining about unassigned outputs, so we should focus our efforts on investigating what happens with `y`. It turns out you never assign a value to `y`! So the function does not know what it should give back when it is called. So, after you display `true` or `false`, you should try to assign that value to a variable `y`, e.g. `y = true`.